# Looking for CiviSMS extension. New version?

Tags: civisms

I'm trying to install CiviSMS on a Drupal based CiviCRM install. I have Drupal 7.43 running CiviCRM 4.7.8 on a CentOS 7 platform.

Comment: Looking for a download for the extension

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the extensions directory on:

https://civicrm.org/extensions
filter for SMS 
Select one and you'll find the download link

Note that both Clickatell and Twilio don't have a 4.7.x stable version listed yet - best to contact their authors to see where things are at.

Comment: yes, looked in that directory and did not see anything. message on install page says mass messaging is broken in civicrm 4.6 and to upgrade to 4.7 or move backwards.  I moved to 4.7.4. Now I don't see a CiviSMS extension to install at all.

Comment: Extensions are community contributed code - usually heavily sponsored by larger non-profits - many of whom are currently still on 4.6 - like I said best to contact the authors to check in on their future plans.

Comment: Twilio shows an extension on https://civicrm.org/extensions/twilio-sms-provider that has a file dated May 25 2016 stating support for CiviCRM 4.7.  I've installed this manually but still having trouble getting it to setup as an SMS provider.